# pass additonal parameter in a Sqlalchemy ORM query towards Rqlite to be able to set query level (access local read only copy or master)

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am using an Rqlite cluster in a Python3/Sqlalchemy environment and would like to be able to specify if an ORM query (db.session.query(Mytable... )) shall access the local read-only copy or go to the remote master.

Rqlite allows to specify a parameter in the http GET query request (named 'level') in the pyrqlite.cursors.execute() function.
I have some trouble understanding how I in the high level Sqlalchemy query can make sure this parameter gets set - per query.

The problem occurs after update when I do query again on same row. To secure that not stale data is fetched, I must be able to tell that such a query shall go to master.
I can probably do a raw query with curs.execute() but that is not what I want.

I would have hoped that setting some sort of PRAGMA and by slighly modifying the cursor.execute() I would be able to pass a (PRAGMA) flag which can be used to set Rqlite level.

I do not want to always query master. The absolute majority of queries will not be have a problem with slighly older data, but I do want to be able to sometimes query shortly after an update wihout risking stale data.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved would be appreciated.

Comment: I did a dirty solution where I request a specific dummy column (by default deferred) each time read consistency is required. In pyrqlite/cursors.execute() it is checked if this column is included in operation. If so, db http req is set to read consistency required. It works but not really state of the art solution.